# Как сделать флеш элемент ссылкой

Tags: html, css

Есть такой код, работает в хроме, но в Опера и Файрфокс не работае. Пробовал события онклик - не помогает.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
<a style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top: 0; background: url("1px.gif"); overflow: hidden;" href="http://test" title="testimSwf" target="_blank">&nbsp;</a>

 <object style="z-index: -99;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="468" height="60">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.blago.ru/files/banners/blago_468x60.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<embed src="http://www.blago.ru/files/banners/blago_468x60.swf" wmode="" `quality="high" menu="false" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="468" height="60"></embed>`
</object> 
</div>
```

Comment: Можете выложить пример с работающей флешкой? Я сейчас ваш код у себя проверил - встраиваемый объект находится позади элемента `a`.

Comment: 1. Пропишите жестко z-index для флеша.
2. Чтоб ссылка везде была корректна, она должна быть не пустой. &nbsp; - вполне подойдет.

Но лучше все-же делать ссылку в самой флеше, так как, по-моему в фаерфоксе, при ряде факторов флеха все равно пойдет поверх оверлеем.

Comment: Обновил пример на который сейчас есть. Все равно ни в Опере, ни в Файрфоксе не работает.

Comment: `<a style="... url(" ..."></a>` Вот в этом месте уже ошибочка! Три точки все что у вас до и после.

Comment: Не в том дело. Браузеры - причем это зависит от версии - не всегда встраивают графику плагина в конетекст страницы. Многие просто лепят канву сверху и отдают её плагину - и все зашибенно быстро рисуется.

Сделайте картинку 1px какойнибудь красной и прозрачностью 50% (PNG24) и посмотрите на красоту в разных браузерах.

Собственно, если кто-то напишет живое решение буду очень рад - реально интересно.

Answer (score 2):

Иерархия по важности (позиционирование на передний план):

```
window
object, frame, iframe, embed
select
прочий DOM
```

В старых браузерах (особенно IE) это очень явно можно наблюдать. Попробуйте не позиционировать ссылку, а обернуть ею флеш ролик, соответственно присвоить ей display: block. Иногда срабатывает. А вообще, да, лучше прописать линк в самом ролике. Но некоторые разработчики роликов забывают об этой важной мелочи, но оставляют лазейку вида: gotoURL(_root.link1) в скриптах флешки. Такой код позволяет переадресовывать пользователя по GET переменной link1. Чтобы узнать, есть ли в ролике такая строчка, - лично я, пользуюсь Sothink SWF Decompiler. Остаётся прописать эту переменную в инициализацию ролика. Что-то вроде:

```
<param name="movie" value="http://www.blago.ru/files/banners/blago_468x60.swf?link1=http://example.com" />
<param name="link1" value="http://example.com" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность отредактировать елемент, то можно создать слой и поместить его поверх всех остальных слоев и вставить такой ActionScript код:

```
 on (release) {
    getURL("адрес, куда ведет елемент", как откроется ссылка(например: _blank));
}
```